# ComboBox doesn't show any of its strings

Tags: haskell, combobox, gtk3, gtk2hs

I just started using gtk2hs (gtk3 on hackage) and have run into some issues with comboBoxes.
I cannot make a simple comboBoxNewText display its strings. I have commented out everything unneeded in my application so I just have a basic framework for the actual box.

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  set window [windowTitle := "Table", containerBorderWidth := 20,
              windowDefaultWidth := 800, windowDefaultHeight := 600]

  table <- tableNew 10 10 True
  containerAdd window table 
  lbox <- hBoxNew False 0
  rbox <- hBoxNew False 0
  tableAttachDefaults table lbox 0 3 0 10
  tableAttachDefaults table rbox 3 10 0 10

  cb <- comboBoxNewText
  comboBoxAppendText cb "test"
  boxPackStart lbox cb PackGrow 10

  on window deleteEvent $ liftIO mainQuit >> return False
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI
```

Am I missing something? gtk3 is marked as unstable iirc on hackage, could this be a bug? Or am I just doing something incorrectly?
Adding `comboBoxSetActive cb 0` doesn't help either. To clarify, the actual combobox appears when I run the program, but it doesn't contain any strings/is blank.
[evernote image](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s93/sh/65cb8ea6-5e23-4390-8a28-f75fdd066cf5/38f08051fce7990bad1247e4a40f2ff1)

Comment: Is the combo box completely empty, or does it contain the correct number of blank entries?

Comment: It is completely empty, when clicked it displays a window just wider than the box and only a few pixels high.

Comment: This exact code works when linking against gtk instead of gtk3. So it seems like there's probably a bug in the gtk3 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Wagner commented, this does seem to be a bug in the gtk3 package on hackage. It was fixed with the commit attached to the issue linked https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/10